# Disable Fancybox Pop-Up With Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, fancybox

I have a Fancybox set on a delay to pop up on any page of my Wordpress, I'm looking to have it become disabled after a user submits something in the provided input or have it not show up for a given amount of time if the user clicks on the bypass link. I've tried a few scripts found around this site but nothing seemed to work, here's what I currently have set in place.

```
function openFancybox() {
        setTimeout( function() {$('.pop').trigger('click'); },20000);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var visited = $.cookie('visited');
        if (visited == 'yes') {
            return false;
        } else {
            openFancybox();
        }
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 7 });
        $('.pop').fancybox();
    });
```

Comment: why do you have two separate document ready functions? Also, have you used firebug / web developer tools to see the values of you're cookie in the various states?

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript haha, I'm a designer just trying to teach myself this stuff.

Comment: I would suggest only including the code that is relevant.. everything below line 13 isn't.

Comment: @CoreyTegeler - so i'll take it that is a "no"? The first thing you should do is open firefox, get the add-on firebug.  Clear your cookies, open firebug, refresh your page and look under the cookies tab of firebug, you can then find your cookie and make sure the values are being set / update properly.

Comment: Just edited everything else out, was just making sure there wasn't a conflict with the rest of the code.

Comment: @Brad okay I'll give it a try, but I don't know exactly what I would do with that knowledge haha, the code I have above was taken from someone else and not sure if it really applies to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below to see if that helps.

```
openFancybox = function{
   setTimeout( function() {$('.pop').trigger('click'); },20000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   //Declare your cookie.
   $.cookie('visited','no', { expires: 7 });

   //Test to see if your cookie equals 'no', if true then run the fancy box.
   if ($.cookie('visited') == 'no') {
           openFancybox();
   }

   //Your Input or click to stop the fancy box
   $('#StopFancyBox').on('click',function(){
       $.cookie('visited', 'yes');
   });
});
```

As @Brad mentioned you can use the web developer tools to test to see what your cookie value is at stages. Simply go to the web.console and call back `$.cookie('visited')`

**ERRORS**

```
jquery.cookie.jsGET http://www.coreytegeler.com/bolivares/wp-content/themes/max-magazine/source/cookies/jquery.cookie.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The above seems to be because the jquery.cookie.js file is not referencing the right location.

```
/bolivares/:72SyntaxError: Expected token '('
```

The above is actually my fault :) sorry. When declaring the function openFancybox i missed off the (). So it should be `openFancybox = function(){`.

```
jquery-plugins.min.js:13TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.browser.msie')
superfish.js:123TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery('ul.nav').superfish()')
woocommerce.min.js:1TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'e(".plus").live')
```

The above are conflicts with the plugins jquery-plugins.min.js, superfish.js and woocommerce.min.js respectively. I'm sorry I can't give much guidance on these.

```
/bolivares/:259ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myLoop
```

You're calling back myLoop(i) on line 259 on your main html page. But searching through all of your scripts, this isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: Still pops up on each load

http://www.coreytegeler.com/bolivares/
you can view it here

Comment: Having a look at your site, you have **a lot** of errors. The cookie is not being created in the first instance even before we get to the fancy box. I've edited my answer with all of the errors. I would highly suggest correcting all of these errors before hand and you will likely find your cookie will work.

Comment: Haha, yeah thanks for that, I don't know what any of that means but I'll look into it. Sorry for being an amateur but I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem I'll have a look at your scripts and will try to help, please check my edit in about 10 mins

Comment: Thanks! just looked over and fixed most of the errors, that last one I realized the function I created was supposed to be myLoop but when I change it to that the pop-up comes back right after you close it and only works properly if I don't declare that myLoop at the top haha (?)

Comment: Brilliant so is all working now? Don't forget to tick and answer if it has helped your question :)

Comment: Oh sorry no haha, I mean it works properly as in without the new issue. The pop up still shows up on every page.

Comment: Ok i've had another look at your site. You have more issues than are being reported. First you are using different versions of jquery 1.7 & 1.9... problem is you can't just remove one or the other because you have sooooo many plugins that they are not all compatible with just one version. Second you have an extra quote on line 573 of your index.html... third you have html (<meta> tag) inside a script tag on line 625 of index.html. Fourth you need to add `()` to the function on line 72 of index.html... But the main problem is the multiple jquery libraries.

Comment: I attempted to fix the issues the best I could but I couldn't seem to find some.

Just a reminder, the code I provided above and have in place could very well just not be the solution to my problem, I ripped it from somewhere and it may just not fit in the context of my needs. Is there another approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can edit it perfectly all you have to do is create a settimeout value so that the fancybox pops out after some time and then write the program like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {$('#fancybox-manual-b').trigger('click'); },5000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 7 }); /*write this first*/
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        function callback(a){
                return function(){
                alert("Hello " + a);
                                    }
                                    }
                var a = "world";
                setTimeout(callback(a), 2000); /*let the page load first*/
                a = "subscriber";
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $('#fancybox-manual-b').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

If you want you can change the (I wrote this to check if the cookie is working properly or not)

```
if (visited == 'yes') {
        function callback(a){
                return function(){
                alert("Hello " + a);
                                    }
                                    }
                var a = "world";
                setTimeout(callback(a), 2000);
                a = "idiotteen";
    }
```

to

```
if (visited == 'yes') {
return false;
}
```

Let me know if this helped you